# Question About Netsuite Certifications for SaaS, PaaS and CaaS Employees

Tags: netsuite, saas, paas

[Curriculum for Netsuite Certs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aFoj.png)

I feel like an idiot for posting this out in the open, but does the table above for certifications for CaaS, SaaS and PaaS employees using Netsuite make sense? Your inputs would really help a guy get employed!

I have zero knowledge in IT, no friends who use Netsuite and just read up as best as I could. I'm interviewing for a Training Role and the company asked me to prepare a curriculum (I plan to expand more on this later which I believe I can do on my own).

Comment: This question isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your starting point would be the NetSuite Certification page on the Oracle NetSuite website (https://www.netsuite.com/portal/services/training/suite-training/netsuite-certification.shtml).  That lays out the recommended code and prerequisites for each Certification.